# Find the total of words as one number with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been using the JS code for the Facebook API for finding the total number of words in the messages.

What I have tried is:

```
#THE MAIN CODE IN THE API

function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me/inbox?limit=10',function(response) {
        for (var i=0;i<response.data.length; i++) {
            var thread = response.data[i];
            var babe = 0;

            for (var j=0;j<thread.comments.data.length;j++) {
                var comment = thread.comments.data[j].message.length;
                babe += comment;

            }

            console.log(babe);

        }
    });
}
```

When I do this i get the output like 135, 75... what I need is to find their sum  like `135+75 = 210` and display it.

I have tried many methods but am still stuck with it; hope you guys can help me.

`console.log(thread)` gives like

```
Object {id: "272328299637636", to: Object, updated_time: "2014-08-07T06:13:18+0000", unread: 0, unseen: 0…}
comments: Object
id: "272328299637636"
to: Object
unread: 0
unseen: 0
updated_time: "2014-08-07T06:13:18+0000"
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but, I have a comment regarding how you ask. Don't be offended but, it would be nice if you put it on a nice format. Like fixing your code. E.g. the indentations and such. In short, make it look like presentable like you're on a meeting with the big bosses or professors.

Comment: I can't see any reason you would get that. It's what you would get if either of the arguments to `+` were strings, but you're adding numbers.

Comment: If `thread.comments.data[j].message` is a string, `.length` is the total number of characters in the string, not the number of words.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the edit .btw how can i do it ??..can you just give me the idea ??..i have tried like many methods

Comment: @Barmar when i did it ..it gives me the string ..not the numbers

Comment: You can get a word count with `message.split(' ').length`.

Comment: Can you please put screenshot of developer console? We'll have a look

Comment: Can you show `console.log(thread)`?

Comment: @Barmar what i need is to find the number of words in the messages ..it would be helpful if u post the code as an asnwer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
var comment = thread.comments.data[j].message.split(' ').length;
```

This will count the number of words in `message` rather than the number of characters.

And to get a single total for all the threads, you need to initialize the counter outside the first loop:

```
function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me/inbox?limit=10',function(response) {
        var babe = 0;
        for (var i=0;i<response.data.length; i++) {
            var thread = response.data[i];


            for (var j=0;j<thread.comments.data.length;j++) {
                if (thread.comments.data[j].message) {
                    var comment = thread.comments.data[j].message.split(' ').length;
                    babe += comment;
                }

            }    
        }
        console.log(babe);

    });
}
```

Comment: it gives the numbers but its showing like 12,45,78,45, etc ..what i need is to find its total of those numbers ..what i need is one number as the total not many numbers

Comment: I can't explain that, unless you're initializing `babe` to `'0'` instead of `0`, or doing something else that converts numbers into strings.

Comment: see what i need is to find the total ..and var comment fetches the message string

Comment: I know what you need to do. And this code SHOULD DO IT. I don't know why it's not working for you, you must be doing something wrong that you didn't show in your question.

Comment: see when i use llimit = 1 it works fine ..it shows otuput like 101 which is right ..and when i changed the limit it shows like 101,15 ..i dont know why ..my json response is http://pastebin.com/RLxxvcfi

Comment: That's because you're doing a separate console.log for each thread.

Comment: then how can i make it one ??..can you please tell me ..:)

Comment: see the code works just fine when i add limit = 10 ..but when i did limit = 15 it says  like cant read property split of undefined

Comment: I've added a check that `message` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `thread.comments.data` is array / collection of string..

If you do something like this :

```
var stringArr = ["This is string 1", "Hello, I am string 2", "Hola, I can say, I am string 3.,....", "Namaste, India"]
var count = 0;
for(i=0; i< stringArr.length ; i++)
{

    count += stringArr[i].length;
}
console.log("Total Count is - " + count);
```

You should get the total count..

**As per your API response, I have edited the demo. Problem was in some objects "messages" property wasn't defined.**

Demoed here : http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/cs2xdsbp/

Comment: It looks like `thread.comments.data` is an array of objects. These objects have a `message` property, and it contains a string.

Comment: it gives an infinite loop ..:/

Comment: Can you please post the exact response you get in JSON format?

Comment: @RahulPatil sure hold on